# How to format a DATETIME for database insertion?

Tags: php, database

I have a database that people post to and the posts get inserted.

I want to log the date and time in the database too, using the `DATETIME` column type. How would I do this using the `date()` function?

Comment: You will probably want to use [gmdate](http://us1.php.net/gmdate) rather than `date`, that way you can be sure the date you're working with is UTC. This will make it easier for you to handle timezone differences among your users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From mysql [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

So in PHP you just need to use the [date](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo datetime; // display example: 2014-01-27 17:21:34
```

Answer (score 2):

> Different Ways to format Date time in php

```
<?php
#The two example outputs are based on this time
#eg1: 2010-06-19 15:09:35
#eg2: 2010-06-19 08:30:59

echo date("Y-m-d");
#Output eg1: 2010-06-19
#Output eg2: 2010-06-19

echo date("n/j/y");
#Output eg1: 6/19/10
#Output eg2: 6/19/10

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
#Output eg1: 2010-06-19 15:09:35
#Output eg2: 2010-06-19 08:30:59

echo date("l, jS F Y h:i a");
#Output eg1: Saturday, 19th June 2010 03:09 pm
#Output eg2: Saturday, 19th June 2010 08:30 am

echo date("jS M y g:i A");
#Output eg1: 19th Jun 10 3:09 PM
#Output eg2: 19th Jun 10 8:30 AM

echo date("D, j M Y G:i:s");
#Output eg1: Sat, 19 Jun 2010 15:09:35
#Output eg2: Sat, 19 Jun 2010 8:30:59
```

Credit to [nazly](http://www.nazly.net/php-date-function-usage-and-examples/)

Comment: And which one is the proper one for insertion to a database?

Comment: dear, it depends on your business domain and functionality

Comment: @Cobra_Fast , i mostly used echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Answer (score 2):

Doing this can address your concern:

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

You can also set your `DATETIME` column to have a default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
$my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
INSERT INTO my_table (date_time) VALUES ('$my_date');
```

[php DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert the current time, you don't need PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/date) (and figure out the proper format string) - just use MySQL [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (insert_time) VALUES (NOW());
```

Comment: What if I want to insert an arbitrary date other than right now?

Comment: This answer should probably be accompanied by "**If** you want to insert the current time, don't use PHP `date()`...", otherwise use `date()` as others have suggested

Comment: @Cobra_Fast The OP explicitly wants *to log the date and time [when the posts getting inserted] in the database*

Comment: @Bojangles Updated the answer accordingly.